# HtmlUnit Android problem with WebClient

Tags: java, android, webclient, htmlunit

HtmlUnit is amazing, in Java at least I have had no problems with it. Unfortunately when switching the code over to the Android platform, it is giving me errors when I try to create a web-client.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    }
}
```

Warnings it gives me before the program starts on the AVD.

This is an example of the warning it gives me, this is the exact warning but it is repeated over and over about 100000x times:

```
 [2011-08-31 21:25:24 - AndroidTest] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap$1) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is not an inner class.
```

Is there any help you can give me?

Error in android debugger:

```
09-01 07:44:24.569: WARN/dalvikvm(877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.Test.AndroidTestActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestActivity.java:20)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.URLCreator$URLCreatorStandard.toUrlUnsafeClassic(URLCreator.java:66)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlUnsafe(UrlUtils.java:193)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlSafe(UrlUtils.java:171)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     at       com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<clinit>(WebClient.java:162)
09-01 07:44:24.600: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(877):     ... 14 more
```

**ERROR AFTER ADDING COMMONS-LANG AND REST OF LIBRARY

```
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:157)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:180)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.Test.AndroidTestActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestActivity.java:21)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-02 16:16:34.440: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which version of HtmlUnit are you using?

Comment: 2.9, newest version, I also just discovered that a webrequest does work. while a webclient doesnt.... odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stacktrace shows that an `ExceptionInInitializerError` is thrown and that it is caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

Perhaps you're missing some JAR (commons-lang) in the classpath?

Comment: Thanks very  much, only 1 more error left :) I edited the original question to reflect the next error

Comment: I added the htmlunit class into my project so I dont understand why I am getting the  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandle error

Comment: @user828727: You're missing the HtmlUnit JAR in your classpath, try adding it.

Comment: how? I have the htmlunit-2.9.jar in my classpath as well as the htmlunit-core. I go to project, right click and go to properties (this is eclipse). Then I go to add jars (since the jars are in my project folder) then I add them. Is this wrong?

Comment: @user828727: Here's the list of [HtmlUnit dependencies](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html). And yes you seem to be adding them correctly to the classpath.

Comment: I think it is working correct now, thanks so much. Unfortunately I think all the .jar classes I have added make the application too heavy. When I try to install it on my phone it wont even install it and it has troubles running on the emulator :(

Comment: is it possible that the application just has too many jars in its classpath to run?

Comment: @user828727: I'm not sure, but why don't you create a new question?

Comment: also do you have any ideas about this error?
-it gives me it about 1000x times...
Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an      
anonymous inner class

Answer (score 1):

I have that similar problem. After some research, i found that this is due to namespace conflicts. You must recompile the sourcecode of htmlunit. I try to this now, but the htmlunit is so large and complex that i have not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special Android version of HtmlUnit (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android) that should solve most of the issues related to not existing classes in the android jdk.

There is also a hint about the commons-lang problem on the page.

Using this also requires to update your sources to HtmlUnit 3 - see https://www.htmlunit.org/migration.html for some hints.