# HTMLUnit doesn't work

Tags: java, android, htmlunit

I have written a program to login to a website with HTMLUnit, wich works great. Now I want to use it in the Android app I am building but it doesn't work. I am getting this error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Once I remove a few jars, like the Jetty jars, I keep coming across this error

```
Could not find class 'com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision', referenced from method com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.init
```

and a few seconds later this one:

```
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/css/CSSCharsetRule
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:703)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.processClass(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:444)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.buildUsageMap(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:409)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:365)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:381)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.<init>(JavaScriptEngine.java:130)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:218)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:193)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:184)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.cofely.VPNProfileLogin.doInBackground(VPNProfileLogin.java:28)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at com.cofely.VPNProfileLogin.doInBackground(VPNProfileLogin.java:1)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    ... 5 more
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.css.CSSCharsetRule
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-19 13:47:26.485: E/AndroidRuntime(18991):    ... 19 more
```

Can anyone tell what is going on here? Thanks

Comment: You've mentioned two issues. Regarding the second one, if you `remove a few jars` and then you get a `Could not find class` error then I'm pretty sure you've removed more jars than you should have :)

Comment: Yes I realize that, but I need to find some way in between. Since I need the classes, but I can't use thos jars

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:
["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Not 100%  sure about this, but you might need to convert some jars referenced in your project to dalvik format using:

```
dx --dex --output="c:\temp\dx.dex" "c:\temp\in.jar"
```

You get `NoClassDefFoundError` errors probably because you removed necessary jars from project.

Comment: I already tried most of those top answers, eventually resultuted in me losing all my files

Answer (score 0):

There's an dependency missing. You don't have the JAR in your APK which contains the org.w3c.dom.css.CSSCharsetRule definition.

After a short Google search I found this posts:
[Getting HtmlUnit to run under Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014212/getting-htmlunit-to-run-under-android)
[how to use htmlunit with my android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885422/how-to-use-htmlunit-with-my-android-project)

It seems to be much easier to rewrite your **scraper** to use jSoup instead of HtmlUnit if you need it to work on Android too.

Comment: Yes, I did figure that out. However, I think it might be in one of the jars that is causing the Dalvik error

Comment: @BlackMagic is there some Top Level exception above the Dalvik 1 error?

Comment: Nope, thats the first and only error it gives in that situation

Comment: @BlackMagic see my updated answer. Seems to be a knownproblem with no working solution.

Comment: I only found one .dex file, wich is classes.dex. And I am not sure wether I can just convert it